# NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/api/DataTable when trying to upgrade to Cucumber 4

Tags: java, cucumber

I am trying to upgrade my tests to Cucumber 4. I am using testNG and Maven.

I have updated my dependency versions for the following:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
            <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I keep getting the error 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/api/DataTable' when trying to run a test.

This is my runner:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.*;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"XXXX"},
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    glue={"XXXXX"},
    tags = {"@XXXXX"})

public class Cucumber4Runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
```

}

I have tried to ensure all versions of dependencies match up but struggling!

Comment: Could you please comment if your problem has been solved and how. Would be nice to know for other SO visitors with a comparable problem.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you have not aligned the import statements (other changes might be needed).

From the [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

> 3.0.0
>   ...
>   [Core] Replace DataTable with **io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable** (#1248 M.P. Korstanje, Björn Rasmusson, Marit van Dijk)

Based on your exception message your code is looking for **`cucumber.api.DataTable`**

**edit** There might be also a transient dependency from one of you other dependencies to an older cucumber version.

Assume the following dependencies only in your `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <version.cucumber>4.2.0</version.cucumber>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

listing the project dependencies

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

would produce the following tree

```
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.cucumber:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.cucumber:gherkin:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |        \- io.cucumber:datatable-dependencies:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.testng:testng:jar:6.14.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.72:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache-extras.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b6:compile
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-guice:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] \- io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:pom:4.2.0:compile
```

Have a look if there is somewhere a dependency to

- `info.cuke:*` any version
- `io.cucumber:cucumber-core` version before 3

Comment: Does this mean that somewhere in my code, I have an older version of Cucumber trying to do something? If I can't see the error in my pom/dependencies, do you have any suggestions on how it might be fixed?

Comment: @L.Ball Have a look to my updated answer. There might also be a transient dependency to an older cucumber version.

Comment: thanks - I did already try this, and no reference to info.cukes. All cucumber jars in the tree seem to be version 4.1.0. Puzzled!

Comment: @L.Ball Have a look if you have a dependency to a `cucumber-core` with version < 3. I updated my answer.

Comment: @L.Ball Could you please add the whole dependency tree to your question.